# XML file Generator

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio

Any recommendations for XML generators in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few XML generators for C++. Some of them work with DOM, others can serialize your classes, and yet others work in even more different ways, like Boost.PropertyTree. Whichever you should choose, depends entirely on your requirements.

If you need to write a small set of data to an XML file (and may also want to write this data to other formats in the end), consider using [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/property_tree.html). If you want to serialize C++ classes to XML, or make C++ class representation of XSD Schemas, consider using a binding generator such as [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/). And if you just want to manipulate the XML directly, you can use a DOM parser/writer like the cross-platform [Xerces C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/).

Answer (score 4):

[MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a sensible option if you're limiting your application to Windows.
[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) could prove useful if you're wanting to write code that can be ported to other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a few that exist already, but if one were inclined to implement their own it would be an easy task using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/quick_start.html).

Comment: Reading the XML spec isn't that easy a task, let alone implementing it ;-) Of course if you don't care about anything other than simple elements and attributes, it's pretty easy.